# How to write Unit Test Case for Linq Expresssion Dot Net

Tags: .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, testcase

How to write Nunit Test Case for following Linq Expression?

```
public IQueryable<City> Query(Expression<Func<City, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your unit tests should be checking that your custom logic is working as expected.
I think you are trying to test the framework code which should be working fine.